# Finding optimal combination of covariates using cross validation

Tags: mixed-model, cross-validation, lme4-nlme, model-selection

I have a logistic mixed model (lme4 package in R). I want to assess whether participants scores on the measures 'sumspq', 'sumpdi', and 'sumcaps' significantly affect the difference in performance between 2 conditions.

I first run the model:

performance ~ Condition*(sumspq+sumpdi+sumcaps)+ (1|participant)

Results show none of the interactions are significant (all ps >.05)

I check variance inflation factors and confirm that there is no multicollinearity. To double check, no separate simple regressions with the each predictor produces a significant result (e.g., performance ~ Condition*sumspq + 1|participant)

I also want to add covariates to the model to see if these influence the results (an exploratory analysis with limited hypotheses).
Covariates are: Age, IQ, sumsens1, sumsens2

An automated stepwise procedure for mixed modelling (buildmer package) is used to find the optimal model with covariates included. In this procedure, the interactions of sumpdi, sumspq, sumcaps are forced to be kept in the model as the variables of interest. The model produced is:

performance ~ Condition*(sumspq+sumpdi+sumcaps+sumsens1)+ Age + IQ + (1|participant)

and has significant effects of Condition*sumsens1 (p=.007), age (p=.02), IQ (p=.04).

THE PROBLEM:

My goal is to ensure that I have selected the optimal model to report. I have noticed that the p-values of the covariates greatly vary based on the combination of covariates included in the model. This is despite there being no evidence of multicollinearity. How do I select the optimal model in terms of  confidence in the stability of the estimates/p-values?
I have tried using train/test cross-validation (caret package in R; 0.62 accuracy), but I realise this demonstrates the predictive power of the model (generalising to a new dataset) rather than finding the optimal (even out of poor-performing) models.

Comment: What do you plan on doing with the model you want to select? It does not seem to be predicting. Do you plan on doing inference? If so, please note that *any* model selection process will bias your p-values downwards, quite possibly invalidating them, with no good way of correcting for this.

Comment: My primary goal is to assess whether sumspq, sumpdi, sumcaps (the main predictors) significantly affect difference in performance between the 2 conditions. It is clear that none of these predictors are sig. However, I find it concerning that often the combination of predictors change p-values in the absence of multicollinearity (in this case, for the covariates). I realise adding predictors based on theory is ideal (and my selection of covariates is based on this here). However, this is a very exploratory analysis so theory is limited.

Comment: OK, thanks. Since this is exploratory, wouldn't finding the best model *for prediction* make the most sense? You can always overfit a model to achieve a good in-sample fit, but the proof of *any* model is whether it generalizes. That said, that p values change as you introduce interactions is completely normal, why does this concern you?

Comment: Thanks! I'm concerned because the p-values seem to change drastically based on which covariates are added. For example, with
~Condition*(sumspq+sumpdi+sumcaps+sumsens1)+IQ
IQ main effect is n.s. (p=.05) 
but after adding Age (p=.02), IQ becomes significant (p=.038).
I suppose this is partly because p-vals having a cut-off. But sometimes I find the significance changes more drastically. I suppose I want to report a model that best reflects the "true" (for this dataset) associations between performance and the predictors. The instability of p-vals based on the exact model concerns me.

Comment: I would not consider such a small change in p values concerning. (Have you seen "The dance of the p values" on YouTube?) Also, you have a very large model. I hope you have a commensurately large number of observations, at the very least multiple hundreds.